# How to store value of checkboxes in table to an array and pass onto another jsp page?

Tags: jsp

[if i check 3 checkboxes from attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx3sb.png)

i want to check multiple checkboxes and store their value into an array.

I am using below code but its just storing only one value.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnApprove" name="btnApprove" onclick="getTaskId();"  value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="btnApprove" name="btnApprove" onclick="getTaskId();"  value="2" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
function getTaskId(){
    var id=Array();
    id = document.getElementById('btnApprove').value;
    console.log(id);
    
    
    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have found the solution for this.

```js
   function printChecked(){
       
    var items=document.getElementsByName('btnApprove');
    var selectedItems="";
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
     if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true)
      selectedItems+=items[i].value+",";
    }
    
            console.log(selectedItems);
   }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnApprove" name="btnApprove"  value="1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="btnApprove" name="btnApprove"  value="2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" id="btnApprove" name="btnApprove"  value="3" checked/>
<input type="submit" name="RunScripts" value="Run Scripts"  onclick="printChecked();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same id in same document is not detectable, so you have to avoid same id , you can do like this

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="btnApprove" onclick="getTaskId(this);"  value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox"  name="btnApprove" onclick="getTaskId(this);"  value="2" />


<script type="text/javascript">
function getTaskId(evnt){
    var id = evnt.value;
    console.log(id);



}
</script>
```

For Group checkbox result as an array for checked item, you can use like below

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="checkbox"  name="btnApprove[]" onclick="getTaskId();"  value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox"  name="btnApprove[]" onclick="getTaskId();"  value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox"  name="btnApprove[]" onclick="getTaskId();"  value="3" />
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getTaskId(){
var array = []
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  array.push(checkboxes[i].value)
    }
  console.log(array);   
}
</script>
```